# NetSuite Record Type for [Web Service Operations] Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I have a Saved Search based on Web Services Operations.  I'm trying to access the data through a RESTlet and I have a working script deployment.  This thing I can't figure out is the correct search type.  I've tried a whole load of combinations but still get this error:

```
[code] => INVALID_RCRD_TYPE
[message] => The record type [WEBSERVICESOPERATIONS] is invalid.
```

Does anyone know the correct datatype I need to use.  Perhaps there is a way of listing them all?  Here is my RESTlet:

```
function getRESTlet(dataIn) {

    var message = "";
    var status = "OK";
    var data = {};

    var savedSearch = nlapiLoadSearch('WebServicesOperations', 'customsearch_mysearch');
    var resultset = savedSearch.runSearch();
    var returnSearchResults = [];
    var searchid = 0;

    do {
        var resultslice = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);

    for ( var rs in resultslice) {
        returnSearchResults.push(resultslice[rs]);
        searchid++;
    }

    } while (resultslice.length >= 1000);

    return returnSearchResults;

} // Close function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid Scriptable/Searchable record types would be found in the [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/website.html). Not all Record Types are available to be scripted or searched via scripting.

`Web Services Operations` does not appear to be supported in scripting.